# Change font size and type in enumerate with enumitem

Tags: fonts, enumerate, enumitem, size

I'm currently trying to customize a ennumerate list with enumitem and i got really far. The only thing i did not manage to achieve is to change the font size and the font itself of the label.

This is what i got so far

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\small
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0em, label=\arabic*, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
\item something
\item something else \newline
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I tried just adding a `\small` after `label=` but it did not work. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks for any help in advance!
gerberli

Comment: `\small` in the label would make it small but it is small already as you have `\small` before the list (which should be `\small` not `\small{`  , size commands do not take an argument)

Comment: If you have an example that does not work as you expect edit the question to post a full small example document so people can run it and debug the problem.

Comment: Do you really want the label to be in the margin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code puts the labels into the margin, since by default, labels are right aligned at the (list) left margin) – I don't think it is what you want. For the font size problem, you have to use the `font` key. Compare with two other codes:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0em, label=\arabic*, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
  \item something
  \item something else. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0em, label=\arabic*, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, font=\small\bfseries\color{red}]
  \item something
  \item something else. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. 
\end{enumerate}

Unless you want this: 
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0em, leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, font=\small\bfseries\color{red}]
  \item something
  \item something else. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I will check it this evening but I think you solved all my problems!

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks again for your help!