# How to get of a situation where enumerate item numeric label is a different font size than the item text?

Tags: beamerposter

I'd like to get out of a situation where the enumerate item numeric label is a different font size than the item text.

I find surprisingly few related questions using search terms such as "enumerate item label change font size".

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397074/change-font-size-and-type-in-enumerate-with-enumitem) may be relevant.

I'm using `beamerposter`.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple in standard classes: using the example in you link the key `font=` does the trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\small
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0em, label=\arabic*, font = \Large\bfseries, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
\item something
\item something else
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer consider this post? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer

Comment: No, I didn't even know it. But knowing beamer redefines a lot of things, I took the precaution to mention standard classes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,height=5,width=5]{beamerposter}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=red}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{size=\huge,
series=\bfseries,family=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bah   
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```